# Merge 2 tables from different databases no matching fields into a temp table on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, merge, temporary

I'm working on a project and I'm stumped. I have 2 websites that take orders. The databases are on the same server. Each website stores the order data into tables in separate databases. The primary site uses "dbo.Orders", which is the  table that is used to give data to our aspdotnetstorefront backend. Our sales people use this interface to review orders. The secondary site uses"dbo.orders", which is the table used to store orders. The second site's orders are not accessible on the aspdotnetstorefront. My job is to merge the orders from the secondary site into the table for the primary site so the orders can be seen on the aspdotnetstorefront backend like the orders from the primary site. I also have to create an identifier so when viewed the sales people will know which site the order was from. I think creating a temporary table and maybe an outer join or merge? Problem is the tables have no matching fields. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION ALL` to combine the records

```
SELECT 1 as SiteID, 
       * -- common fields
FROM   Database1.dbo.Orders
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 as SiteID, 
       * -- common fields
FROM   Database2.dbo.Orders
```

Fields in Database2.dbo.Orders will have to be the same type as the Field in Database2.dbo.Orders. For example, the following will not work.

```
SELECT 1 as SiteID,
       CustomerName -- VARCHAR
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as SiteID,
       OrderDate    -- DATETIME
```

Add fillers if you need to, if a column exists only in one table and you need to include it in the query.

```
SELECT 1 as SiteID,
       CustomerName as CustomerName,
       NULL as OrderDate  -- filler to match OrderDate
FROM   Database1.dbo.Orders
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as SiteID,
       '',  -- filler to match CustomerName
       OrderDate
FROM   Database1.dbo.Orders
```

To create a temp table you can add the `INTO [TABLE]` syntax to the first select.  Also example using your `OrderNumber` `ordId` fields

```
SELECT 1 as SiteID, 
       OrderNumber
INTO   #temp -- create temp table to hold all rows generated from union
FROM   Database1.dbo.Orders
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 as SiteID, 
       ordId  -- will appear in second column [OrderNumber]
FROM   Database2.dbo.Orders
```

Comment: Just another small question. The dbo.Orders has 20+ fields. So does dbo.orders. Does the name have to match exactly? For example dbo.Orders has OrderNumer and dbo.orders has ordID. Same thing but different name. Will these merge or will all differently names fields have to be "filler"?

Comment: Also am I making a temp table?

Comment: Names don't have to match.. just the data types.. so as long as `OrderNumber` and `ordID` are both the same type it's fine.. You can convert the types to match if you need to also.. the `UNION ALL` will use the name from the field in the fist select as the column name for all tables below.  This is not making a temp table.  Just a query. You can certainly insert the results into a temp table if you'd like.

Comment: You indicated that matching fields like OrderNumber and ordID, when union, ordID will be the second column. I was attempting to merge all similar fields and create a identifier to know which site the order came from. Once the second table is merged, it can be seen in the orders on the aspdotnetstorefront.if the 2(Orders and ordID) are merged into one column. Union will do this or will it make 2 seperate columns?

Comment: Meaning with there be a OrderNumber column and and ordID column with a union? Is a merge better to bring together the 2 fields?

Comment: I'm going to create a SQL Fiddle for you so you can see the output

Comment: dont feel too bad, whoever created a table with 150 columns was lost also